# How to use ionic slides?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to use the simplest possible slide feature by using:

```
  <ion-content>
    <ion-slides>

      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Page1</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Page2</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Page3</h1>
      </ion-slide>

    </ion-slides>
  </ion-content>
```

TS:

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-intro',
  templateUrl: 'intro.html'
})
export class IntroPage {    

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
  ) { }


  goToTabPages(){
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage, {welcome_flag:true});
  }

}
```

...and I am getting the error below:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
>       at initSwiper (swiper.js:84)

After searching about that, I could not find any solution. Only people who simply use it in the same way as me, but that had their code working. If anyone has any idea of what it could be, it would be very helpful.

Thanks for reading,
Roger A Leite

Comment: Hi Roger, please Read this link - https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/

Comment: Hello Keval, it just doesn`t work. It doesn`t matter what I do, it is still displaying " Cannot read property 'classList' of null at initSwiper " and I have no idea what is it about =/.

Comment: @RogerAlmeidaLeite Can you show your typescript code as well?

Comment: @StevenScott, thanks for your reply. Concerning the TS, I just added it in my question, there is nothing special about it. I was trying to get the minimum working and later create more functionalities on the top of it and so on. However, the minimum is not working and I have no clue why. Also, I just found another person with the same issue from 1 year ago https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/rc5-component-slides-js-init-swiper/76854 .

Comment: I would try to get your app.component.ts, app.module.ts, etc. into the question as even the 1 answer below also indicates that their is code we are not seeing.  Your error is from code outside what you have posted, and that is likely what is contributing to your issue.  Even TabsPage is not defined in your code block, but I am assuming you are importing it above, but it becomes easier for everyone to help you if all the code that is relevant is available.  You could simply build a basic project with just 2 pages and the slider and post the code to help people help you.

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like there's something else going on with your code, because the error that you're showing doesn't seem to have anything to do with the code that is in your question.

Whenever I've seen that particular error of the form "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'whatever' of null at 'wherever'"  it's specifically because I am trying to get a property from an object that I haven't defined or loaded properly.  For example, if I had something like:

> var beer = drink.isGood

but, I never defined or loaded "drink" properly in previous code, it would error out with: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isGood' of null"

Your existing typescript code is probably more important than you think... because I don't even see the properly "classList" in the code that you supplied.